# Is there a global grep.conf in Unix/Linux?

Tags: grep

I would like to make a utility that always enables the `--color` argument for the `grep` command in any distribution. Is there a way to do this or do I have to search for a way for each distribution?

Comment: I'm not aware of _any_ grep.conf file, and `--color` isn't globally available (maybe on current Linux systems, but probably not on quite a few other "Unix" systems).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These simple GNU tools don't have config files. You can use shell aliases.

```
alias grep="grep --color=auto"
```

Put that in your `~/.bashrc` file (or equivalent to what you use). Then you will always use that alias for the `grep` command.

Comment: Or better yet, give it a different name like `cgrep`. If you *always* invoke `grep` with `--color`, it will mess up other commands that read its output.

Comment: @KeithThompson The `auto` directive tells it to only use color if the output is to a tty. If you pipe it to another program there won't be color codes in the output.

Answer (score 2):

There is no configuration file for `grep`, but is does listen to environment variables. Check the `man grep`, search for 'ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES'

These variables can easily be set in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile. If you want to make changes global for all users, edit `/etc/profile`.